# Delayed Jobs with Action Mailer using Mailjet API on a Heroku Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, mailjet

Looking to send a delayed jobs mailer with Mailjet's API, but the emails are not being sent.  All works locally with Foreman, but again, on development on Heroku is not sending. The delayed jobs table was created.

Here's the gemfile

```
gem 'mailjet'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

The controller

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
    # send email to referral email
    all_users = User.all
    all_users.each do |user|
      ArticleMailer.delay.article_confirmation(user,@article)
   end 
   redirect_to @article
    else
     render 'new'
    end
end
```

The mailer

```
class ArticleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def article_confirmation(user,article)
    @user = user 
    @article = article 
    Mailjet::MessageDelivery.create(
      to: user.email,
      from: "[EMAIL]@gmail",
      subject:  "[HTML]",
      html: "[HTML]

  end

end
```

The /environments/development.rb file

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "in-v3.mailjet.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "[OURDOMAIN].com",
    authentication: "login",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "[OUR_USERNAME]", 
    password: "[OUR_PASSWORD]",
    require_ssl: true 

}
```

The schema

```
  create_table "delayed_jobs", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   default: 0, null: false
    t.integer  "attempts",   default: 0, null: false
    t.text     "handler",                null: false
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "delayed_jobs", ["priority", "run_at"], name: "delayed_jobs_priority", using: :btree

  create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "slug",                      null: false
    t.integer  "sluggable_id",              null: false
    t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 50
    t.string   "scope"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end
```

UPDATE:

When I run `Delayed::Job.last`

```
=> #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 181, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2014-12-01 19:04:25", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2014-12-01 19:04:25", updated_at: "2014-12-01 19:04:25">
```

Comment: Have you started rake jobs:work?

Comment: Yup - this is our Procfile: 'worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work'